# How many times was Nicolas Flamel mentioned in the Harry Potter books?

Tags: harry-potter

I am working on a project for science (we have to create a periodic table). I can't seem to find out how many times Nicolas Flamel was mentioned in the books.

Comment: What do *Harry Potter* and Nicolas Flamel have to do with creating a periodic table?

Comment: Flamel created the Philosopher's Stone, right? Alchemy... Chemistry...

Comment: Maybe Mendeleev was one of Flamel's alter egos.

Answer (score 6):

## Total Count: 29

### *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*: 27

#### Page 81

> [...] for the discovery of the twelve uses of dragon's blood, and his work on alchemy with his partner, Nicolas Flamel. Professor Dumbledore enjoys chamber music and tenpin bowling.

#### Page 154

> "I'm tellin' yeh, yer wrong!" said Hagrid hotly. "I don' know why Harry's broom acted like that, but Snape wouldn' try an' kill a student! Now, listen to me, all three of yeh -- yer meddlin' in things that don' concern yeh. It's dangerous. You forget that dog, an' you forget what it's guardin', that's between Professor Dumbledore an' Nicolas Flamel --"
>
> "Aha!" said Harry, "so there's someone called Nicolas Flamel involved, is there?"

#### Page 157

> "Oh, we're not working," Harry told him brightly. "Ever since you mentioned Nicolas Flamel we've been trying to find out who he is."

#### Page 158

> "We just want to know who Nicolas Flamel is, that's all," said Hermione.
>
> [...]
>
> They had indeed been searching books for Flamel's name ever since Hagrid had let it slip, because how else were they going to find out what Snape was trying to steal? The trouble was, it was very hard to know where to begin, not knowing what Flamel might have done to get himself into a book. He wasn't in Great Wizards of the Twentieth Century, or Notable Magical Names of Our Time; he was missing, too, from Important Modern Magical Discoveries, and A Study of Recent Developments in Wizardry. And then, of course, there was the sheer size of the library; tens of thousands of books; thousands of shelves; hundreds of narrow rows.
>
> Hermione took out a list of subjects and titles she had decided to search while Ron strode off down a row of books and started pulling them off the shelves at random. Harry wandered over to the Restricted Section. He had been wondering for a while if Flamel wasn't somewhere in there. Unfortunately, you needed a specially signed note from one of the teachers to look in any of the restricted books, and he knew he'd never get one. These were the books containing powerful Dark Magic never taught at Hogwarts, and only read by older students studying advanced Defense Against the Dark Arts.

#### Page 159

> "And you could ask your parents if they know who Flamel is," said Ron. "It'd be safe to ask them."
>
> [...]
>
> Once the holidays had started, Ron and Harry were having too good a time to think much about Flamel.

#### Page 165

> He'd be able to read as long as he liked, as long as it took to find out who Flamel was. He set off, drawing the invisibility cloak tight around him as he walked.

#### Page 168

> Anyway, maybe it only shows dead people. Shame about notfinding Flamel, though.
>
> Harry couldn't eat. He had seen his parents and would be seeing them again tonight. He had almost forgotten about Flamel.

#### Page 173

> She was torn between horror at the idea of Harry being out of bed, roaming the school three nights in a row ("If Filch had caught you!"), and disappointment that he hadn't at least found out who Nicolas Flamel was.
>
> They had almost given up hope of ever finding Flamel in a library book, even though Harry was still sure he'd read the name somewhere.

#### Page 175

> "I've found him!" he whispered. "I've found Flamel! I told you I'd read the name somewhere before, I read it on the train coming here -- listen to this: 'Dumbledore is particularly famous for his defeat of the dark wizard Grindelwald in 1945, for the discovery of the twelve uses of dragon's blood, and his work on alchemy with his partner, Nicolas Flamel'!"
>
> "Nicolas Flamel," she whispered dramatically, "is the only known maker of the Sorcerer's Stone!"

#### Page 176

> There have been many reports of the Sorcerer's Stone over the centuries, but the only Stone currently in existence belongs to Mr. Nicolas Flamel, the noted alchemist and opera lover. Mr. Flamel, who celebrated his six hundred and sixty-fifth birthday last year, enjoys a quiet life in Devon with his wife, Perenelle (six hundred and fifty-eight).
>
> "See?" said Hermione, when Harry and Ron had finished. "The dog must be guarding Flamel's Sorcerer's Stone! I bet he asked Dumbledore to keep it safe for him, because they're friends and he knew someone was after it, that's why he wanted the Stone moved out of Gringotts!"
>
> "A stone that makes gold and stops you from ever dying!" said Harry. "No wonder Snape's after it! Anyone would want it."
>
> "And no wonder we couldn't find Flamel in that Study of Recent Developments in Wizardry," said Ron

#### Page 182

> "Hermione, the exams are ages away."
>
> "Ten weeks," Hermione snapped. "That's not ages, that's like a second to Nicolas Flamel."

#### Page 183

> "Yer not still lookin' fer Nicolas Flamel, are yeh?"

#### Page 239

> "Destroyed?" said Harry blankly. "But your friend -- Nicolas Flamel --"

#### Page 244

> "So the Stone's gone?" said Ron finally. "Flamel's just going to die?"

### *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*: 2

#### Page 20

> He not only won every prize of note that the school offered, he was soon in regular correspondence with the most notable magical names of the day, including Nicolas Flamel, the celebrated alchemist; Bathilda Bagshot, the noted historian; and Adalbert Waffling, the magical theoretician.

#### Page 242

> Had he thought that there would be time; that he would live for years, for centuries, perhaps, like his friend Nicolas Flamel?

Comment: You included all the mentions of “Flamel,” so good work. But there are a few mentions of “Nicolas” too, without the “Flamel.” Maybe you should add those.